# Dynamic paint - bake multiple displacement surfaces

Tags: baking, dynamic-paint

I'm trying to simulate sand build up after something dips into it (with dynamic painting). I'm using two parented spheres as brushes (one bigger one smaller). The smaller one is in collection "down" and the bigger in collection "up". I have one plane which is canvas with TWO surfaces. One named "down" that uses the collection down and has displacement factor on 2 And second one named "up" that uses collection "up" with displacement factor -1 so it displaces upwards.
[image]

When i play the animation in viewport without baking the result is what I want like this.
[image]

but when i try to bake the frames it only bakes one of the surfaces not both... Something I'm missing or is there better, different way to do this similar effect? Thanks, tedd.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into the exact same problem under the exact same circumstances. This happens because you didn't name the cache sequences, so baking one always overwrites the other. They need to be given unique names.[image]

Comment: Wow, I'm facepalming right now, Im gonna try it. Thanks!

Comment: np, took me a while to figure it out too :)